# How to set the rowHeight of a row without affecting the rowHeight of another row with C# and Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using a .xltx template file with a logo in the A1 cell and then an empty row with a background colour on A2 (which will act as my column headings row). When the excel document gets generated, I want to set the `rowHeight` of the logo row to a specific height and set the `A2` row to another specific height. However, both rows' height are set exactly the same (the height of the `A2` row).

```
excelWorksheet = excelApplication.ActiveSheet;
//Getting the image row range
var imageRowRange = ((Worksheet)excelWorksheet).Range["A1", "A1"];
var entireImageRowRange = imageRowRange.EntireRow;
//Setting the image rowHeight
imageRowRange.RowHeight = 48.75;
//Getting the second row which acts as the column heading row
var rowRange = ((Worksheet)excelWorksheet).get_Range("2:1");
var entireRowRange = rowRange.EntireRow;
rowRange.WrapText = true;
if (setCustomHeight())
    rowRange.RowHeight = 0.75 * int.Parse(getCustomHeight());
else
    entireRowRange.AutoFit();
rowRange.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignBottom;
rowRange.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
```

How can I set the first row individually from the second row please?

Comment: change `get_Range("2:1");` to `get_Range("2:2");`, so that you only target the second row?

Comment: Great, thanks Keith. Please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change `get_Range("2:1");` to `get_Range("2:2");`, so that you only target the second row.

Range `2:1` means all rows from 2 to 1, range `2:2` means all rows from 2 to 2. You can test this by typing the range in Excel's "Name" box in the top left.

[image: excel selected range]